# How to set single clicking to open file in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm, rubymine

And what are counterparts to eclipse's declaration view and javadoc view?

Comment: I suggest changing the accepted answer to Rostyslav's answer since it works with the current version of Android Studio while the original accepted answer is now years out of date

Answer (score 171, accepted):

In the `Project View` click on the "gear" icon and enable the **Open Files with Single Click** option:

[image: Open Files with Single Click]

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> for **Quick JavaDoc** and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> for the declaration pop-up.

Comment: Great! Someone knows of a way to make the file close again when clicking on another file?

Comment: @SimonBengtsson Coming from Sublime, this is the feature I crave the most.

Comment: @Mazyod you stole my words... I really thought that was addable

Comment: @SimonBengtsson Get rid of tabs altogether!  You won't regret it!  I tried it and I'll never go back.  You can easily switch "tabs" using Ctrl/Cmd + E.  Couple it with Zen mode and it feels super awesome ;)

Comment: @SimonBengtsson `Enable preview tab` may do the trick. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68426661/6042295

Comment: same place, the "gear" icon.  but called differently.  see the answer by @Rostyslav

Comment: This plugin does it like VSCode if anyone is interested. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12778-quick-file-preview

Answer (score 52):

Now it's available in a simpler way. In the `Project View` click on the `Gear` icon and then click `Open Files with Single Click`:

[image]

Comment: how to set this feature enabled by default for all projects ? if i open new project i have to set this every time

Comment: @Anton, I don't know. Agree with you it's really annoying. If you find the solution, please post it here.

Answer (score 28):

Go to Preferences and turn on `Enable preview tab`, that will enable `Open Files with Single Click` for all projects.

[image]

Comment: I am wandering why intellij team, has give both the option for same work!!

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc opens with **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>**

There's no declaration view *per se*, however, you probably will be satisfied with **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>** shortcut for quick lookup.

Don't know of any ways to configure it to open files on single clicks. Somehow, if you get used to the shortcuts, you skip using mouse very much. For instance, **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>** will bring the navigation bar up and you can move with arrows and open the file with **<kbd>Enter</kbd>**. Or just use some other shortcuts like **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>** or **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>** depending on the context.

Answer (score -1):

- In the Project View click on the Gear icon
- Uncheck "Autoscroll to Source" in Project view settings

[image]